# Use twemoji to parse "3 letter" emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, emoji, emoji-tones, twemoji

I'm trying to use the `twemoji.parse()` function to render "3 letter" emojis, like "‍♀️" which would be a female detective with dark skin.

**Here is what I tried:**

### Try one

`twemoji.parse("‍♀")`

Result:
[image]

---

### Try two

`twemoji.parse("♀‍")`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that this library does support combined emojis, I think the most likely answer is simply that they don't have support for combining detective + female yet. Did you consider a feature request?

Comment: Well, those emojis were introduced in the Emoji 4.0 spec, while Twemoji supports Emoji 5.0 according [to there README](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/blob/gh-pages/README.md). I opened an issue about that [here](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/issues/247)